# Git : Is there any way to add a submodule without cloning it?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am trying to add `facebook/MySQL5.6` as my submodule, but the repo is so huge that I can't clone it in a short time.

What I want to do is just add it as my submodule and I don't need to change any code.

Is there any simple way to make it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Clone the `MySQL5.6` repo with `--depth 1` then only the last commit and only the branch you specify (or the default branch) is cloned. This should save you a big amount of time for cloning.

Comment: Seems submodule doesn't have this option ?

Comment: Why submodule? You said you need to clone it to add it as submodule. That is an option of clone.